# Node.js | Converting endpoint to a generic path to match in YAML file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, yaml, swagger

I am developing a mock server that will use the Swagger-Parser package to process the incoming requests and return a response, the details of which are specified in a YAML file. For example, if the server received a request as `api/locations/assign`, I will look for the exact `api_path` in the YAML file and if found, I will parse it further to check for headers and request body.

```
getInfoFromUrl(req) {
    var paths = req['url'].split('/');
    return {
        host: req.get('host'),
        organization: paths[2],
        product: paths[3],
        api_path: `/${paths[4]}/${paths[5]}`,
        method: req.method.toLowerCase()
    };
},

// gets data related to the path from yaml file
// returns 404 Not Found when provided path does not exist in .yaml
getPathData(res, api, url) {
    var pathData = api['paths'][url.api_path][url.method]; // get all possible responses for that path

    if (pathData == null) {
        res.status(404)
            .send(`The path ${url.method.toUpperCase()} ${url.api_path} does not exist`);
    }

    return pathData;
}
```

The problem arises when path parameters are involved. For example, the YAML includes a path GET `api/locations/{location-id}`. However, the request I will receive will be GET `api/locations/4`.

Is there any way to know the `key` (name of the path parameter) of the corresponding `value`? So that when I receive `api/locations/4`, I can convert this into `api/locations/{location-id}` and look for it in the YAML file? Or if there is any other approach you think I can take, please feel free to let me know!